# Tkinter using memory when updating image; how do I stop the memory usage?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an image to display on the main page which I am updating every 10 seconds. I open the image, set the label than then make a reference back to the image so that it does not get garbage collected and disappear.
As soon as I take the "plant_stat_panel.image = plant_stat_img" it stops chewing up the memory. What is the correct way to update an image and cleanup after yourself to stop the memory consumption?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root= Tk()

def img_updater():
    plant_stat_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/wateringsys/html/temp.png"))#/home/pi/html/
    plant_stat_panel = Label(root, image = plant_stat_img)
    plant_stat_panel.image = plant_stat_img
    plant_stat_panel.grid(row = 5,column = 0, columnspan=2, sticky = W )

    root.after(10000, img_updater)

root.after(0,img_updater)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are making a new Label every 10 seconds and covering up (not deleting) the older ones. You need to make the Label once, and *update* the Label, not create a new one every time.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root= Tk()
plant_stat_panel = Label(root)
plant_stat_panel.grid(row = 5,column = 0, columnspan=2, sticky = W )

def img_updater():
    plant_stat_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/wateringsys/html/temp.png"))#/home/pi/html/
    plant_stat_panel.config(image = plant_stat_img)
    plant_stat_panel.image = plant_stat_img
    root.after(10000, img_updater)

img_updater()
root.mainloop()
```

As soon as you make overwrite the old image, the python garbage collector will automatically free the memory. In python, you should not need to worry about memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly! I was mulling over it in the middle of last night.